# Is there a simple way to check if all the properties in a queryset have same value?

Tags: python, django

If I have a Queryset containing a bunch of objects, is there a simple way to check that a property of all those objects contains a specified value?

`my_queryset = Employees.objects.filter(team='East1')`

Now I want to check that all these employees have cost_centre='E150'.
At the moment I'm doing a loop through the queryset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if there is such `Employee` that has a `cost_centre` different from `'E150'`:

```
assert not Employees.objects.filter(
    team='East1'
).exclude(cost_centre='E150').exists()
```

So if there is an element here, then that means there is at least one employee that has not `'E150'` as `cost_center`.

You can obtain the `Employee`s with:

```
Employees.objects.filter(
    team='East1'
).exclude(cost_centre='E150')
```

and you can update all employees to that `cost_center` (if you want to do that) with:

```
Employees.objects.filter(
    team='East1'
).update(cost_centre='E150')
```